# looping through Javascript Object returning sum of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, object

What I'm trying to do is loop through an object getting the total times that each candidate appears and print that to the page.

I've have been racking my head on this one. I'm new to javascript and working with objects is something very new to me.

Thank you for the help!

```js
var entry = [
  {
    candidate : "guy1",
    rank : 1,
    state : "AK",
    vote_count : "2"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy2",
    rank : 1,
    state : "MI",
    vote_count : "3"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy3",
    rank : 1,
    state : "AK",
    vote_count : "5"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy2",
    rank : 1,
    state : "AL",
    vote_count : "4"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy2",
    rank : 1,
    state : "FL",
    vote_count : "9"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy1",
    rank : 1,
    state : "MN",
    vote_count : "7"
  }
];

for ( var i = 0, l = entry.canidate.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    guy1 += entry.canidate[i];
}

console.log(guy1);
```

Comment: To be clear, are you looking to get the number of times a candidate appears, or total up the number of votes for that candidate?

Comment: `canidate !== candidate`. What is your question?

Comment: You have a type `entry.canidate` should be `candidate`. Also, `entry.candidate` is not a collection. `entry` is a collection.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I'm looking to get the total times that each candidate appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an object with the candidates as key and count the votes.

```js
var entry = [{ candidate: "guy1", rank: 1, state: "AK", vote_count: "2" }, { candidate: "guy2", rank: 1, state: "MI", vote_count: "3" }, { candidate: "guy3", rank: 1, state: "AK", vote_count: "5" }, { candidate: "guy2", rank: 1, state: "AL", vote_count: "4" }, { candidate: "guy2", rank: 1, state: "FL", vote_count: "9" }, { candidate: "guy1", rank: 1, state: "MN", vote_count: "7" }],
    count = {};

entry.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a.candidate] = (count[a.candidate] || 0) + +a.vote_count;
});

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Why didn't use reduce like other answers?

Comment: because in this case reduce returns always the object `count`, which is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object with the summation of votes by candidates like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/he58xsb8/

```
var entry = [
  {
    candidate : "guy1",
    rank : 1,
    state : "AK",
    vote_count : "2"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy2",
    rank : 1,
    state : "MI",
    vote_count : "3"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy3",
    rank : 1,
    state : "AK",
    vote_count : "5"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy2",
    rank : 1,
    state : "AL",
    vote_count : "4"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy2",
    rank : 1,
    state : "FL",
    vote_count : "9"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy1",
    rank : 1,
    state : "MN",
    vote_count : "7"
  }
];

var voteByCandidate = {};
for ( var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++ ) {
    var result = entry[i];
    if (!voteByCandidate[result.candidate]) {
        voteByCandidate[result.candidate] = 0;
    }
    voteByCandidate[result.candidate] += result.vote_count * 1; // Convert to number.
}

console.log(voteByCandidate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a candidateMap and loop entry array .for each same candidate increment the key in the map.

```
var candidateMap = {};

entry.forEach( function(candidate) {
   candidateMap[candidate.candidate] = candidateMap[candidate.candidate] || 0;
candidateMap[candidate.candidate] += 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with reduce:

```js
var entries = [{ candidate: "guy1", rank: 1, state: "AK", vote_count: "2" }, { candidate: "guy2", rank: 1,  state: "MI", vote_count: "3" }, { candidate: "guy3", rank: 1, state: "AK", vote_count: "5" }, { candidate: "guy2", rank: 1, state: "AL", vote_count: "4" }, { candidate: "guy2", rank: 1, state: "FL", vote_count: "9" }, { candidate: "guy1", rank: 1, state: "MN", vote_count: "7" }];
var result = entries.reduce(function(r, c) {
  r[c.candidate] = (r[c.candidate] || 0) + parseInt(c.vote_count);
  return r;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to get the total times that each candidate appears

You can use array [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the candidates then [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to count the number of occurrence of each candidate

```
var _filter=[];
entry.filter(function(item){
  _filter.push(item.candidate)
})

var _reducedArray =_filter.reduce(function(prev,next){
        prev[next] = (prev[next] + 1) || 1;
        return prev;
    },{});

console.log(_reducedArray);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yoxgtaag/)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need:

```
const votes = {};
entry.foraEach(item => {
    if(!votes.hasOwnProperty(item.candidate)) {
        votes[item.candidate] = +item.vote_count;
    } else votes[item.candidate] += +item.vote_count;
});
```

You will have all the candidates and votes inside the `votes` object.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var entry = [
  {
    candidate : "guy1",
    rank : 1,
    state : "AK",
    vote_count : "2"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy2",
    rank : 1,
    state : "MI",
    vote_count : "3"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy3",
    rank : 1,
    state : "AK",
    vote_count : "5"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy2",
    rank : 1,
    state : "AL",
    vote_count : "4"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy2",
    rank : 1,
    state : "FL",
    vote_count : "9"
  },
  {
    candidate : "guy1",
    rank : 1,
    state : "MN",
    vote_count : "7"
  }
];

function getCandidateTimes(entry, candidateName){
  var appearTimes = 0;
  for (var i=0, len = entry.length; i < len; i++){
    if(entry[i].candidate == candidateName){
      appearTimes++;
    }
  }
  return appearTimes;
}

var guy1AppearTimes = getCandidateTimes(entry, 'guy1');
console.log('guy1 appears ' + guy1AppearTimes + ' times!');

var guy2AppearTimes = getCandidateTimes(entry, 'guy2');
console.log('guy2 appears ' + guy2AppearTimes + ' times!');

//and so on.......
```

Comment: you may consider adding some explanation over your answer.

Comment: i am so sorry that to answer without any explanation, and it is my first time  answer question in stackoverflow..